# How to solve git: fatal : unable to access <some_repo>...?

Tags: git, gitlab

When I try on gitlab :

```
  git push --set-upstream origin master
```

This is not a repo that I own, I just have access to gitlab. I suspect the repo owner has to give me access.

I get this error:

```
fatal: unable to access '<somegitrepo_ongitlab.git>': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I tried changing the user and email like this:

```
git config user.name my_gitlabuser
git config user.email my_email
```

Still getting the same error.... How to solve this?

git remote -v results in:

```
 origin somegitrepo_ongitlab.git (fetch) 
 origin somegitrepo_ongitlab.git (push)
```

git remote show origin:

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: somegitrepo_ongitlab.git
  Push  URL: somegitrepo_ongitlab.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (local out of date)
```

Comment: Looks like you've copy+pated a command to set the remote, without replacing some placeholder text with the url. What is the output of `git remote`?

Comment: Or did you actually edit the error message before posting it here?

Comment: see above mate !

Comment: Have a look at `git remote show origin`

Comment: have a look @Christoph above

Comment: @bierhier I'm still very much unclear whether/how much you have redacted the error message. Does it **literally** say "`somegitrepo_ongitlab.git`"?! Or does it show the full path, i.e. `git@your_server:namespace/your_project.git` - where those are real values, not a copy+pasted placeholder?

Comment: "I suspect the repo owner has to give me access." < this is really the first thing to confirm. What access have you been given?

Answer (score 1):

**fatal: unable to access '': The requested URL returned error: 403** 
As you have developer access for pushing your code to particular project perhaps you are not able to push.. :( 
You need to add your identity first using

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

and again try to push code to project
`git push --set-upstream origin branch-name`

Answer (score 0):

I think, you did not setup your remote correctly: it should look something like that:

```
.../test (master)
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/Christoph999/test
  Push  URL: https://github.com/Christoph999/test
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

Perhaps, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43364619/5784831) helps