# Having trouble adding files to an existing, empty github repository

Tags: git, github

First, I created a repository on github that is obviously empty. Then I initiated a git bash terminal in my working directory. Once I do that, I'm using the following code to push my files to the github repository:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "my commit"
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repo.git
git push origin master
```

When I run `git push origin master`, I get the following error:

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:/madsthaks/AdTrackingFraudDetection.git'
```

I'm not very comfortable with git so I'm having a bit of trouble with this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the Github desktop app?

Comment: I don't, just using a gitbash terminal

Comment: Download the desktop add; clone the repository; then you can just drag the files in to your local repo. Then do the commit and push

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43364619/5784831)? What does the information about your remote look like?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
git init
echo. readme>README.md
git add .
git commit -am "Initial Commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/madsthaks/AdTrackingFraudDetection
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Comment: doesnt it request username and password? Whats OS are you on? GIt version?

Comment: Or just use the ssh url like in the question. The main point here is the `--set-upstream`