# Github Push failed: Failed with error: RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: error:140943FC:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3

Tags: android, github, push

When i am Trying to push my android project to GitHub i got this **error**

> Failed with error: RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read:
>   error:140943FC:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad record
>   mac, errno 0 The remote end hung up unexpectedly The remote end hung
>   up unexpectedly

Comment: Please show all commands you use...

Comment: **git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/x/y.git
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"  
push -u origin master**


Counting objects: 93, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (81/81), done.
Writing objects: 100% (93/93), 1.78 MiB | 17.87 MiB/s, done.
Total 93 (delta 44), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: error:140943FC:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad record mac, errno 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/43364619/5784831?

Answer (score 1):

It can be caused by large files in your repo. Github has 100 MB limit for a single file in a repo. You might want to check it by using `git lfs migrate info`.

I've had the same issue but this particular error was intermittent. I occasionally have seen "error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage". Also when I switched to SSH for remote origin instead of HTTPS it gave me broken pipe error message.

I already used LFS but my .gitattributes missed some large files so I've updated it and run `git lfs migrate import --include="*.fileextension"` then pushed to github without an error. See https://help.github.com/articles/moving-a-file-in-your-repository-to-git-large-file-storage/.