# How to visit a git branch of Django project on Nginx/uWSGI server?

Tags: django, git, nginx, virtualenv, git-branch

I have successfully built several web sites hosted on an **Nginx** server using **Django**, **uWSG**I and **virtualenv**.

I had never used version control but now **I am starting to use Git**.

I understand how to create, commit and push branches.

My question is: **how to make different Git branches visible at the web address of the site I'm working on?**

Do I change the **Nginx config file** to point somewhere different?

I just updated the dev branch of my project, and of course the site does not reflect the changes.

**How can I tell the server to serve the dev branch or the master branch of the project?**

I would prefer to avoid a complicated system with different subdomains for different branches — I really just want the simplest thing that will work.

**[update]** I have found lots of pages that explain complex ways to set up staging servers etc., but I really just want to understand what is going on... there's a giant conceptual hole in my understanding about how the server interacts with a local Git project.

Right now, the Nginx config and the uWSGI config point to a folder like:

```
/var/www/sitefiles
```

That is the Django folder (inside it is sitefiles/settings.py etc.).

It is in that folder that I did git init, some commits, branching & pushes.

Does using Git mean that the Nginx and uWSGI config's should point elsewhere?

Comment: Which command did you use? Git push should so the Job... See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43364619/5784831

Comment: I used git push, but I have two local branches, master & dev. How do I tell the server which one to serve?

Comment: Git push -u origin yourbranch. But i am Not sure what you mean with serve...

Comment: Just use git checkout branchname and touch the wsgi file then your server will be using branchname  thats it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its pretty simple goto the path of the project where git is installed and checkout to required banch and touch the wsgi file

```
git checkout dev
touch project/wsgi.py
```

or to roll back to master branch

```
git checkout master
touch project/wsgi.py
```