# How to deploy a local wordpress to bluehost server using git

Tags: wordpress, git, ssh, bluehost

I have a wordpress website in localhost and a hosting plan with a domain name on Bluehost.com
My website is ready and now I wanted to go live and push my website to hosting server using Git. But in Bluehost C-panel there is no git option. 
I have searched google but did not succeed to find a solution, so I came here if somebody could redirect to me to a tutorial link or give me some clues on how to do it i would be very grateful.

Comment: What is the IDE that you are using (e.g. VS Code, PhpStorm...) ? You can use the `git` option/plugin of your IDE to do that.

Comment: I am using VS code

Comment: [VS Code - Connect to remote GIT repository and PUSH local files to new remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43364619/6837428)

Comment: thanks for the link but I didn't understand correctly. my question is, I wanted to upload whole my Wordpress website on a web hosting (Bluehost) somehow using git. I have already created a repository on Github. now in my Bluehost account if I clone my repository from Github. will it work ? or I need some SSH configurations.

Answer (score 0):

If you have VPS or Dedicated server on bluehost, try this manual from Bluehost FAQ:
https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/2383

Pretty sure, that you must manually import database (as it not included to git and can't upload automatically in mysql) and configure again wp-config.php. Also you don't say, what server you using with localhost, cause it can be different from bluehost config (for example apache / nginx / php version).