# git push, when it ask to set upstream and when it and does not

Tags: git

I am not very sure why does `git push` show two different messages for these branches. What is the difference between creating these two branches one with `origin/master` and the other one without.

For the first one: `git checkout -b dev origin/master`

> D:\Source\Projects\dev -> origin\fortnight (dev -> origin)(fortnight@1.0.0)
>
> git push
>
> fatal: The upstream branch of your
>   current branch does not match the name of your current branch.  To
>   push to the upstream branch on the remote, use
>
> git push origin HEAD:master
>
> To push to the branch of the same name on the remote, use
>
> git push origin dev
>
> To choose either option permanently, see push.default in 'git help
>   config'.

And for the other one: `git checkout -b uat`

> D:\Source\Projects\uat -> origin\fortnight (uat -> origin)
>
> git push
>
> fatal: The current branch uat has no upstream branch. To push the
>   current branch and set the remote as upstream, use
>
> ```
> git push --set-upstream origin uat
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS Code - Connect to remote GIT repository and PUSH local files to new remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364233/vs-code-connect-to-remote-git-repository-and-push-local-files-to-new-remote-re)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## TL;DR

If your `push.default` setting is `simple` (or is unset and defaults to `simple`), `git push` will:

1. Require that your branch have an upstream set.  If not, you get the message `fatal: The current branch name has no upstream branch ...`
2. Require that the *upstream* name match—minus the *`remote`* part, that is—the current branch name.  That is, if your branch is named `xyz`, the upstream name must be `origin/xyz`, assuming the remote is named `origin`.

So if you have no upstream set, you get error #1; if you have an upstream set, but it's not one that Git "likes" due to the `push.default` setting, you get error #2.

Of the two ways you're using `git checkout -b`, one of them creates an upstream setting, and one does not.  The actual upstream setting is one that makes `push.default` complain.

## Long

There is not really a good short answer here, because the history of this stuff—what was originally called *tracking* and is now called *setting an upstream*, and the way this upstream thing interacts with each of multiple different Git commands—is long and frankly kind of boring. :-)  Unfortunately you'll need to know at least a little of it, in order to make sense of the way modern (2.0 or newer) Git works.  That's because the Git folks try to maintain compatibility all the way back to Git 1.5, even though nobody actually uses Git 1.5 (hardly anyone uses Git 1.7 any more, even, and anything before 2.0 is really pretty obsolete).

Before I dive into any of this, remember too that `git pull` is really two Git commands combined into one.  What `git pull` does is first, run `git fetch`.  Then, after the fetch works, it runs a second Git command, usually `git merge`.  It works better to talk about these separately—the opposite of `push` is not `pull` but rather `fetch`.  That's due to a historic error, of sorts, as we'll see.

#### The long and boring history, shortened as much as I can

To start close to the beginning and go very fast, the root of the problem is this:   The original `git pull` was a pretty short-and-sweet script: it ran `git fetch`, then it ran `git merge`, and that was it.  Fetch and merge were *usually* the underlying actions you needed, so that's what it did.  But this original `git pull` command was not sufficient, because *usually* isn't *always*.  The script would sometimes destroy your own repository too, if something went wrong or you ran it at a bad time (I had this happen to me at least once).

The script got tweaked many times—it got a lot better, though I got burned enough to learn to avoid it—and eventually re-written from scratch.  The current `git pull`, as of Git 2.6.0 and later, is no longer a shell script, and probably doesn't break repositories any more. :-)  (I still rarely use it myself.)  Meanwhile `git fetch`, `git push`, and `git status` all acquired new features, and all of this stuff got tangled up.

The end result of all this tweaking and rewriting is that, today, each of your branches—your `master`, your `dev`, any other branch that *you* create and *you* control—is allowed to have either *no* upstream, or *one* upstream.  But what exactly is an upstream, and what good is it?  Why do you get these different messages, one complaining that the upstream name does not match, and another complaining that there is no upstream?  And why is all of this so messy and complicated?  We can answer the last part right away: it's messy and complicated because every mistake that was made, over the evolution of these features, is still supported, just in case someone depends on it.

#### Defining the *upstream* setting of a branch name: prologue

The upstream of a branch name is, internally inside Git, extremely simple, but it is defined as *two parts*.  The two parts are a *remote*—which we haven't defined yet—and then a name that's meant to be meaningful *on* the remote.  Hence, before we define *upstream* we have to define *remote*.

#### Defining a *remote* and the corresponding *remote-tracking names*

When you first run `git clone`, you have to give it a URL.  Back in the bad old days, you had to give Git a URL *every time*, over and over again.  Obviously, typing in the same URL repeatedly is dumb.  We have a *computer*, why not have *it* remember the URL?

That's the primary job of a remote.  A remote is just a short, easy-to-type string like `origin`.  This remembers a URL: you can now `git fetch origin` or `git push origin`, and your Git finds the URL using the string `remote.origin.url` as a key in a tiny database.  Of course, if `origin` remembers a URL, it can remember more stuff for you too, so there are more things you can set up using this short name, and there's one super-important one that Git sets up *automatically* for you.

Take a look at your `.git/config` file: view it in a file viewer, for instance, or run `git config --local --list` (or try both).  Note that you have a:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = ...
```

or:

```
remote.origin.url=...
```

setting here.  That's where Git is saving the URL.

What's at this URL?  If you were to call it up with a browser or using `curl` or something, well, it might require you to authenticate / log in / whatever first, but in the end, what's *at* the URL is another Git repository.  That other Git, being a Git, has *its* branches.  You can have your Git *call* that Git, as if making a phone call or sending text messages, via that URL.  The two Gits will then have a conversation.  The exact conversation they'll have depends on what Git command you ran, but there's one you can run any time, that just *shows* stuff from their Git:

```
git ls-remote origin
```

This might show just a little, or a lot, depending on how much stuff they have to tell you.  Here's a snippet of what using it on a Git repository for Git shows:

```
3034dab9ed6b11970a53099a7b3ca981f1461365        HEAD
98e06ded345450b3b07099d3ed1abf58fc95f5b6        refs/heads/maint
3034dab9ed6b11970a53099a7b3ca981f1461365        refs/heads/master
0f2c4a37fdba75d06ae7254c4b30ed7739985214        refs/heads/next
[snip]
213030c8af8ad9f9060cc264395817adb4ede44e        refs/tags/v2.2.3
441c4a40173fe1ee8a5c0094e587dfc47e2a6460        refs/tags/v2.2.3^{}
90141c859541f8daa08bdb0621c64cbd7dadbd8c        refs/tags/v2.20.0
5d826e972970a784bd7a7bdf587512510097b8c7        refs/tags/v2.20.0^{}
[snip]
```

Basically, `git ls-remote` lets your Git ask their Git: *What branches and tags do you have?  What are their corresponding hash IDs?*  That's what spills out here.  When your Git calls up their Git and *gets* things from them, your Git gets to know their branch names.  Your Git then *renames* these branch names: **Their `master` becomes your `origin/master`.  Their `maint` becomes your `origin/maint`.  Their `next` becomes your `origin/next`.**  This renaming—which is actually crazy-flexible; the simple renaming here is just the default—sticks `origin/` in front of *their* names so that you can tell them apart from *your* names.  The literal string `origin/` comes from the fact that you chose to call this `origin` when you set up the remote.

#### Wait, I didn't *choose* `origin`, Git did that!

Well, yes—but that's just the *default*.  If you run:

```
git clone -o boo <url>
```

you'll get a clone that, instead of `origin`, has `boo` as its remote.  Instead of `origin/master`, you'll have `boo/master`, and so on.  If you didn't choose to override `origin`, then, in effect, you chose to use `origin`.

**In any case,** this is what `origin` is all about: it's the name of a remote, and it becomes the prefix of the various *remote-tracking names* that your Git uses to remember *their* Git's *branch* names, the last time you had your Git call up their Git.

This stuff, with remotes and remote-tracking names, was new in about Git version 1.5 or so (details of things pre-1.5 are lost in the mists of time; I didn't start using Git myself until around 1.5.something or maybe even 1.6, and the release notes only go back to Git 1.5.0.1).  Before then, Git didn't have remotes at all, and there were other ways to abbreviate URLs.  Those other ways still work, but you should use remotes and the remote-tracking names.  They are *much* better.

#### If there's an `origin/master`, it makes sense to link your `master` to it

Suppose your Git calls up their Git and your Git finds that they have updated their `master`.  If you do this calling-up with `git fetch`, your Git not only sees the update, it also picks up the new commits they made.  Your Git stores these new commits in your repository—without affecting anything you're doing right now, which sometimes crucial! It's *always safe to run `git fetch`* because of this "don't touch other things" trick—and then your Git updates your `origin/master` to remember the commits you just got from them.

If you're in the middle of something delicate, such as working on a merge, you can just ignore this update for now.  But if / when you're at a nice easy stopping point, or ready to *use* the new commits you got from them ... well, now it's time for you to do something with *your* master, based on what they did with *their* master.  **This is where having `origin/master` set as the upstream of your `master` becomes useful.**  So this gets us back to the second half of setting an upstream.

Note, by the way, that when you use `git fetch`, there's a good chance—probably at least 80%—that you'll eventually want to merge or rebase using what you just brought in.  So it makes sense to combine the two operations into a `git pull`.  I still don't, for three reasons: (1) I've been burned too often and have different habits; (2) 80, or even 90 or 95, percent still isn't 100%; (3) I really *like* to inspect what came in, with the fetch, before merging.  (Maybe reason 3 is part of reason 1, but sometimes it drives *whether* I use `merge` or `rebase`, not just *when* I incorporate the new commits.)

#### Defining the upstream setting of a branch name

The upstream for your branch is usually just the remote-tracking name that you use, in your repository, to remember the commits *they*—whoever they are—have in *their* Git, that your Git has copied via `git fetch`.  In other words, you usually want Git to set the upstream of `master` to be `origin/master`.

But, as I mentioned near the beginning, the upstream is actually set in *two parts*.  One is to set the *remote* setting of your branch `master` to be `origin`.  The other is to set the *merge* setting of your branch `master` to be `master`:

```
$ git config --local --list
[snip]
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
[snip]
```

These two settings make the upstream of my `master` be my `origin/master`.  You can try thinking about this as just stringing the remote and the merge together, but actually that doesn't quite work.<sup>1</sup>

You can also set the upstream of one of your (local) branches to be another (local) branch!  For instance, I can create a branch `zorg` that has `master` as its upstream.  If I do, the `git config` above will say:

```
branch.zorg.remote=.
branch.zorg.merge=refs/heads/master
```

The upstream is not `./master` but rather just `master`, in this case.  **You should use the front-end command `git branch --set-upstream-to`** to hide all this weirdness about the `remote` vs `merge` parts of the setting; `git branch` knows exactly how to combine everything, and deal with the backwards-compatibility that makes this configuration also work with an ancient Git.

To find the current upstream setting of some branch, use `git branch -vv` or `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name`, e.g.:

```
$ git branch -vv
* master          9c9b961d7e [origin/master] The sixth batch
[snip]
```

The text in square brackets shows the current upstream.

```
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{upstream}
refs/remotes/origin/master
```

This exposes some more details of how remote-tracking names really work: the full name is actually `refs/remotes/origin/master`, whereas the full name of your master is `refs/heads/master` (note `heads` instead of `remotes/origin`).

---

<sup>1</sup>Not only is there a wrinkle for the special remote name `.`, the `merge` setting is also *mapped* through the `remote.remote.fetch` setting.  The idea here is that the `merge` setting listed in `branch.name.merge` is the name of the branch *as seen on the remote*, so if you have re-mapped their names to unusual remote-tracking names, your Git will do the same mapping automatically, as necessary.  If you know exactly what you're doing, you *can* use `git config` twice, on the two settings, to set or obtain the upstream setting of any particular branch.  It's much easier to use `git branch` or `git rev-parse`, though.

---

#### Whew, OK, so that's what an upstream *is* ... but what *good* is it?

Here, all that history, and those historical mistakes, come right back into the picture.  In the bad old days you just ran:

```
git pull <url> <branch>
```

which had the annoying problem of typing out long URLs.  So this became the shorter:

```
git pull <remote> <branch>
```

where *`remote`* was almost always just `origin`.  But if we have an *upstream setting*, which lists both the *`remote`* part *and* the *`branch`* part internally, `git pull` can just figure both out *for* you!  So now you could just run:

```
git pull
```

The `pull` script would find the current branch name—e.g., `master`—and then get the `branch.master.remote` and `branch.master.merge` settings, and *automatically* run the same thing as it would for `git pull origin master`.

Thanks to all the backwards compatibility, all of that still works exactly as before, and that's the first thing that an upstream does for you.  It lets you run `git pull` with no arguments.  That `git pull` either literally runs `git fetch` and then runs `git merge`, or, as of Git 2.6, uses the code *from* `git fetch` and `git merge`, and automatically fetches from the right Git, and merges with the right commit.

Similarly, setting an upstream lets you run `git fetch` with no arguments: Git looks at the current branch, gets its `remote`—it doesn't need the entire upstream, just the remote—and does a `git fetch` to the right URL.  Setting an upstream lets you run `git merge` or `git rebase` with no arguments too: Git looks at the current branch, figures out the upstream—this time it needs the whole thing—and does a `git merge origin/master` or `git rebase origin/master` if / as appropriate.

So, for these four related commands—`git fetch`, `git merge`, `git rebase`, and `git pull`—setting an upstream means you don't have to type in as much with each command.  That's really pretty much it.

Note that `git pull` *always* runs `git fetch` first, but you can choose to have it runs `git rebase` second, instead of having it run `git merge` second.  In both cases, the upstream setting still controls the arguments to the `merge` or the `rebase`, **if** you run the shortened command.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>2</sup>If you don't use your upstream—if you type in `git pull remote branch`—the second command, whichever it is, uses the tip commit you brought in from the named remote, without using the upstream setting at all.  This gets into some complicated details, including the fact that, again for backwards compatibility reasons, `git fetch` always writes something about *everything* it fetches to a special file named `.git/FETCH_HEAD`.  This dates back to before the invention of remote-tracking names, though it's still actually useful for one-time fetch-and-use operations.

---

#### What good is an upstream, part 2: `git status` and `git branch`

If you use `git branch -vv` or `git status`, sometimes you will see an annotation like this:

```
[origin/master: ahead 1, behind 10]
```

or:

```
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 10 different commits each, respectively.
```

These counts—which Git makes by inspecting which commits are *reachable from* your branch and its upstream, which is another whole very long discussion; I'll just refer to [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/) here—tell you what kind of work you might have to do to re-sychronize your branch with its upstream.  To do that, your branch has to *have* an upstream.

#### What good is an upstream, part 3: `git push`

As with `git fetch`, `git merge`, `git rebase`, and the do-two-of-those `git pull` command, `git push` *can* be run with no arguments at all.  To make that work, Git needs to know two things: *Where do I call up the other Git?* and *What branch name do I ask them to set?*

Again, the upstream provides both pieces of information.  But there are more historical mistakes here that make this complicated.  That's where the `push.default` setting comes in.

It's worth noting here that there's an asymmetry between `git fetch` and `git push`.  When you use `git fetch` to have your Git call up the Git at `origin`, your Git gets a list from them of *all* of their branches.  Your Git can then take all their new commits, as found by using all of their branches, and *rename* all of those to your `origin/*` remote-tracking names.

**This makes it totally safe to run `git fetch` at any time.**  Your Git is not going to disturb any of *your* work; it's just going to get new commits from them and/or update your remote-tracking names.  None of *your* branches are affected at all!

But, while `git push` is the closest thing there is to the opposite of `git fetch`, it's different in a very important way.  When you run `git push origin master`, for instance, you have your Git call up their Git, offer them new commits if needed, and then end this conversation with a polite request:  ***Other Git, please set your `master` to identify the same commit, by raw hash ID, as my own `master`.***  That is, you're going to mess *directly* with their branches.  There's no remote-tracking name over there—no `alice/master`, no `bob/master`, no `riki/master`, there is only just the one `master`.  If they accept your request, they change their branch immediately.

You might argue that this is the opposite of what `git pull` does, since `git pull` (a) fetches and then (b) merges or rebases, which changes your branch in some way.  But step (b) *always* changes, or tries to change, your branch *non-destructively*.  The push operation is only non-destructive—and only *accepted* when made as a polite request like this—if it is a *fast-forward operation* (which again we haven't defined, and I won't here).  There's no merging or rebasing available: only fast-forwarding is allowed.  You can actually run a `git fetch` that performs fast-forwarding on your own branches, instead of updating your remote-tracking names; and if you do that, you make fetch and push into true opposites (but there are more wrinkles and I don't want to get into details here).

Anyway, this now leads back to history and compatibility—and a sort of "breaking change" that resulted in Git going from version 1.9 to version 2.0, rather than version 1.10 (note the current Git is version 2.22, well past a dot-ten release).

Before Git version 2.0, `git push origin`, with no additional arguments, defaulted to having your Git call up the other Git at `origin` and get a list of all its branches, just like `git ls-remote` or `git fetch` would do.  What Git did then was clever, but—as it turned out—another mistake: your Git would match up *your* branch names against *their* branch names.  If you had a `master` and they had a `master`, Git would add `master` to its list.  If you had a `dev` and they had a `dev`, Git would add `dev` to its list.  Having matched up all of your names, your Git would then ask (politely by default, or forcibly with `--force`) their Git to set *all* of these matching branch names, based on *all* of your branch names.

What this means is that if they—`origin`—had a `dev`, and then you made your own *different* `dev` from your `master`, and ran `git push origin` without naming anything specifically, your Git would ask their Git to set *their* `dev` to match your `dev`, **even though your `dev` is not related to their `dev`**.

After this behavior burned too many Git beginners, the Git folks decided to change it.  They added a bunch of new ways to have `git push` behave.  They created a git configuration setting, `push.default`, that you could set.  One setting is called `matching`: that's what Git 1.x did by default.  The new "safe" setting is called `simple`: that's what Git 2.x does by default.

For a very long transition period, `git push` would complain if you had not set `push.default` yourself, telling you that the default behavior was/would-be different in Git 1.x vs Git 2.x.  If you lived through that transition—or are still using a really ancient Git—you will have seen these complaints, and perhaps even have set your `push.default` setting.

Modern Git no longer complains; it just uses `simple` by default.  The `simple` setting requires that you have an upstream set *and* that the two names match.  If you are pushing from your `dev`, you must be pushing to *their* `dev`.  If you are pushing from your `master`, you must be pushing to *their* `master`.

**Note that all of these constraints apply *only* when you run `git push` in the convenient short-cut mode**, where you let your upstream setting tell Git what to push and where.  If you run, say, `git push origin master`, you are *overriding* the current branch, the upstream, and all of this other stuff: you are telling your Git to call up their Git and ask them to set their `master` based on your `master`, even if you're currently on your own `dev`.

#### New branches vs upstreams

Of course, you can create a *new* branch, which won't have an upstream yet, using something like:

```
git checkout -b foo
```

or:

```
git branch foo
```

or:

```
git checkout -b foo origin/master
```

or:

```
git branch foo origin/master
```

or even:

```
git checkout -b foo master
```

and so on.

There are lots of ways to create branches.  When you *do* create a new branch, you can choose to have the new branch have an upstream setting immediately, *provided* you use some other branch name to create it.  The reason for the *provided* part is that the upstream is the name of another branch.  If you create a branch without using another name, what other name would Git use?

OK, but there's a really tricky bit here.  Actually, there are several tricky bits—some of this is historical I think, and some just the fact that Git is very configurable.  First, consider what Git calls *DWIM* (Do What I Mean).  Suppose that you have just cloned a repository, and are on your `master`, but the `origin` repository has `master`, `dev`, `feature/short`, and `feature/tall`.  You can now run:

```
git checkout feature/short
```

for instance, *even though you don't have a `feature/short`*.  This invokes Git's "DWIM mode": Git sees that you *do* have `origin/feature/short`, and turns this into:

```
git checkout -b feature/short --track origin/feature/short
```

This `--track` option uses the old (bad) verb meaning *set an upstream*.  This creates the `feature/short` branch *and* sets its upstream to `origin/feature/short`.

This same technique works with all the other branch names, and in fact, is how `git clone` made your `master` in the first place.  At the end of the `git clone` process, your Git ran, in effect, `git checkout master`.  You didn't *have* a master, but you did have an `origin/master`.  So your Git *made* your `master` *and* set its upstream to `origin/master`, as the last step of your `git clone`.

If you use:

```
git branch name start-point-name
```

your Git will often, but not always, use the *`start-point-name`* to set an upstream for *`name`*.  You can configure this with the `branch.autoSetupMerge` and `branch.autoSetupRebase` options.  The first has three possible values: `false`, `true`, and `always` for `branch.autoSetupMerge`.  The second has four: `never`, `local`, `remote`, and `always` for `branch.autoSetupRebase`.  These are described reasonably-fully in [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

Some of these automatically-set-up upstreams have names that satisfy `git push`'s `simple` setting, and some do not.  The "DWIM mode" ones always do, so that's particularly convenient.

#### A new branch that has no corresponding name in the other Git

Suppose you do:

```
git checkout -b dev
```

to create a new branch `dev` in your own Git, *and* there's no `dev` in their Git, over at `origin`.  You might like to set the upstream of `dev` to `origin/dev`, so your next command is:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/dev
```

This is what happens:

```
$ git checkout -b dev
Switched to a new branch 'dev'
$ git branch --set-upstream-to origin/dev
error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/dev' does not exist
hint: 
[snip]
```

I'll show the rest of the hint in a moment, but the point here should be clear enough: `origin` *does not have* a `dev`, so *we* do not have an `origin/dev`.  Hence we cannot set the upstream of our `dev` to be our `origin/dev`!

What we'll have to do—well, the sensible option for what we *should* do anyway—is: go ahead and do some work if we want, and soon—maybe even right now—*ask* their Git to create *their* `dev` based on our `dev`.  As soon as they create a `dev`, our Git will create, in our repository, our `origin/dev`.  Then we'll have a name we can `--set-upstream-to`.

So, here is the rest of the `hint` output:

```
hint: If you are planning on basing your work on an upstream
hint: branch that already exists at the remote, you may need to
hint: run "git fetch" to retrieve it.
hint: 
hint: If you are planning to push out a new local branch that
hint: will track its remote counterpart, you may want to use
hint: "git push -u" to set the upstream config as you push.
```

That `git push -u` recommendation is just a short-cut.  We can now run:

```
git push origin dev
```

which will immediately create a `dev` on their system, matching our `dev` (pointing to the same commit hash).  Then we can run:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/dev
```

But it might be nice if we could ask our Git to do *both of these at the same time*, and that's what `git push -u` does:

```
git push -u origin dev
```

has our Git call up their Git, ask them to create a new `dev` based on our `dev`, and then—if that succeeds—do a `git branch --set-upstream-to` as well.

You only *have* to do this once, and even then only if you're using *some* of the various `push.default` settings.  You *can* use the `-u` option more often if you want: it just keeps running that extra `git branch --set-upstream-to`.  If your branch already has an upstream, you'll re-set it: if that's no change, the re-setting is harmless.  If your branch doesn't have an upstream, you'll set it: now you have an upstream.  It almost seems like `-u` should be the default, doesn't it?  But that wouldn't be backwards-compatible: `git push` didn't set an upstream before, so it doesn't now either.

#### There are tons of additional configuration options

There are many more configuration options you can set, that affect `git fetch`, `git push`, `git pull`, and more.  You can, for instance, fetch from one remote and automatically push to a different one—or a different URL for the *same* remote, which is probably only useful if you have the ability to fetch without authenticating but can only push with authentication *and* authentication is slow or painful for some reason.

Some of these options influence things like *why* `git push -u` isn't the default, too.  For the most part, *most* of these things are set up as well as they can be, given the backwards-compatibility constraints that Git faces.  If you find some aspect of Git annoying, check to see if there's a configuration to fix that, because there often *is*.  In this particular case, for instance, you could change your `push.default`.  But consider, too, that in some cases—including this one—the defaults were arrived-at through painful experience, kind of like the way I avoid using `git pull`. :-)

Comment: this is an amazing answer. Thank you @torek.