# fatal: repository 'https://github.com/asifbilaliems/IEMSCode/tree/master/Apps/ReportsProject/' not found

Tags: github, repository

I have just checked the origin and i found this:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/asifbilaliems/IEMSCode/tree/master/Apps/ReportsProject (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/asifbilaliems/IEMSCode/tree/master/Apps/ReportsProject (push)

but still, i am getting this issue:
$ git push origin master
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/asifbilaliems/IEMSCode/tree/master/Apps/ReportsProject/' not found
```

any suggestion? is this because of I am accessing a folder inside the repository?

Comment: Isn't IEMSCode your repository? In that case, your path should only be https://github.com/asifbilaliems/IEMSCode .

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin https://github.com/asifbilaliems/IEMSCode
git push -u origin master
```

See e.g. [here](https://www.atlassian.com/de/git/tutorials/syncing).
See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43364619/5784831) for the process.