# Add Project from Github to AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, git, github

I know there are a lot of answers about this topic but I can't find my problem.

So my problem is I'm working with a friend on an AndroidStudio Project. He made the repository and also made some commits yet. So now I want to add the Project into Android Studio.

The steps how I do that:

Start android > Check out project from Version Control > Git > Then I put in the URL from git > Clone > Then I'm getting a popup "Would you like to create an Android Studio Project" > Yes > Then another Popup > Choose Import project from external model then Android Gradle > Finish

And then Android Studio open a window. The problem is in this window are just .gradle .idea gradle but there is no folder for the source code.

Hope you understand my problem and you can help me.

Comment: A Git solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43364619/5784831)

Comment: I think you have to check your friend's git ignore file. if your friend add gradle file in ignore file, it is not upload.

Comment: Just check out the project and open it in Android Studio, don't create a new Android project

Comment: I don't create a new project @MrVasilev

Comment: @id8909 but you share this "Then I'm getting a popup "Would you like to create an Android Studio Project" > Yes " which for me looks like you create or import a new project. Try just to open the directory with Android Studio after you checked it out

Comment: "Would you like to create an Android Studio Project" > Yes 
This looks like creating a new project. Did you try to clone/checkout the project on the Git console? This would be the first thing I would do and then open it with your IDE

Comment: If I clone it to the desktop for example I get a warning "You appear to have cloned an empty repository"

Comment: @MrVasilev If I don't click create a new project the dialog quits

Comment: I think the easiest solution is: open terminal -> git clone "PROJECT_PATH" -> open android studio -> select THE FOLDER that contains the project. I think before you press open, you are selecting the .gradle file. Try to select  the FOLDER. Also, try to verify with your friend if you .gitignore file is not hidden any important folder or file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a clone link to the project, follow these steps:

```
file -> New -> Project from Version Control.
```

but before following these steps you have to enable your VCS and Configure git.