# remote: Repository not found error in mac terminal

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-remote

I am new to git. I have a private repo and now I want to push the changes of my local to remote repo. However, I get an error:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/co-csp/csm.git/' not found
```

What might cause these error and please help me how to solve it,
I am using **Mac terminal**. My username is **john2** in github profile `git config user.name` and `git config user.username` both gives `john2` so username seems correct...

Comment: 1. Do you have access to this repo ? 2) Did you make sure that there is no spelling mistakes in the url ?

Comment: Is it a private repository? Have you entered the correct credentials?

Comment: Does that help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43364619/5784831

Answer (score 7):

If you are working with a private repository, do the following:

1. git remote rm origin
2. git remote add origin https://user@github.com/co-csp/csm.git
3. git clone https://user@github.com/co-csp/csm.git

This should prompt you to type in the GitHub password and should look like this.

Cloning into 'csm'...
Password for 'https://user@github.com':

Answer (score 4):

Updating credentials from the macOS Keychain

**Method 1: Updating your credentials via Keychain Access**

1. Click on the Spotlight icon (magnifying glass) on the right side of the menu bar. Type Keychain access then press the Enter key to launch the app.
2. In Keychain Access, search for github.com.
3. Find the "internet password" entry for github.com.
4. Edit or delete the entry accordingly.

**Method 2: Deleting your credentials via the command line**

Through the command line, you can use the credential helper directly to erase the keychain entry.

```
$ git credential-osxkeychain erase
host=github.com
protocol=https
> [Press Return]
```

Source: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/updating-credentials-from-the-macos-keychain#updating-your-credentials-via-keychain-access

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities why the `Repository not found` error occurs:

1. **The remote repository does not exist**.
   If you have already set up the remote URL, display it by typing `$ git remote -v` and check that you spelled everything correctly. If you haven't added the remote URL yet, try `$ git remote add origin [URL]` to do so. Also make sure you can find the repo on github; maybe the owner deleted or renamed it. To locally update the URL to your remote repository, type `$ git remote set-url origin [new-URL]`. After that, type `$ git remote show origin` to check whether git can find the remote repo now.
2. **The remote repository is private and you don't have access**. If the repository is private and you didn't authenticate correctly, git will give you the `Repository not found` error even if your remote repository URL is correct. Generally, you can authenticate by using either SSH keys or HTTPS. Using HTTPS, git should normally prompt you for your credentials when it needs them. If it doesn't, try removing your local reference to the remote repo by typing `$ git remote rm origin` and re-add it using `$ git remote add origin [URL]`. I personally prefer using SSH authentication with public and private keys, since it doesn't necessarily require any passwords. You might check out [this link](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/2.15/user/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) to set up SSH authentication for your GitHub, or simply google for it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem

The error was that I had store my personal credentials of github and when tried to made git clone in the terminal automatically set this old credential.

1. You need to clean your old github credential, logout your github account in VS and to make sure (in Mac -> Keychain Access delete the github crendential)
2. Setup your personal token in github

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

3. Login with the new token

   ````
   $ git clone https://github.com/USERNAME/REPO.git
   Username: YOUR_USERNAME
   Password: YOUR_TOKEN```
   ````

and done!

Comment: +1 for this answer. All other IDE Git worked except for the command line git. Removing the password from the keychain and in 2023, we need to supply the personal access token to get this done (no more password).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here. One option is to use `git clone`, the other options is `git init`.

Option 1: Use `git clone`. In a new empty folder put the following command:
`git clone https://github.com/co-csp/csm.git`. You are ready to go.

Option 2: In the project folder, type `git init`. This will initiate an empty new repository. It will create a `.git` folder inside. Go to this folder by typing `cd .git`. Open the `config` file with your favourite editor (mine is `vim`). You will see the following there:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
```

Underneath, append the following:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://github.com/co-csp/csm.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: And why should that help if GitHub returns 404?

Comment: Fair point. Did OP actually create the repository in github?

Answer (score 0):

**Use SSH URL Instead of HTTPS:**

If you were using an HTTPS URL initially, try switching to the SSH URL. Update the remote URL using the following command:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

Replace **username** with your GitHub username and **repo.git** with your repository name