# Git clone authentication failed

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I've set up a new github account and I'm trying to clone a private repo using anaconda prompt. I've never had any issues before on old accounts. After typing the following command:

```
git clone https://github.com/anumana-ts/analytics.git
```

and typing the **correct** (I've confirmed this many times) username and password, I get the following error:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/anumana-ts/analytics.git/'
```

Can anyone tell me what the issue is? I've created and cloned many git accounts in my time but never seen this error before. Thanks.

Comment: Github no longer allows passwords for Git. Use PATs or SSH keys.

Comment: I think you might find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63750973/remote-repository-not-found-error-in-mac-terminal

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with anaconda prompt. Have you tried another terminal? Built in Linux or mac terminal? For me it does not look like a problem with credentials. Please check if the repository url is correct or if your prompt has any issues.

Comment: This is a bit late but changing the terminal worked for me, Thanks @Carlitos

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by downloading the git bash terminal and using that to clone. The terminal redirected me to github where I could sign in using my credentials. I was then able to use the anaconda prompt as normal.

Answer (score 0):

[git clone authentication failed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wm5Ej.jpg)

solution proposal:
Windows 10
Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager

Windows Credentials > Add a Windows Crendial

Add your DevOps platform link > for example:  app.company.local
username: user
password: pass and click ok after try  again