# Cannot push on GitHub ERROR: Repository not found

Tags: git, github, git-push

I am having a very strange problem with git and github. When I try and push, I am getting

```
git push -u origin fix-validation
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I added the remote

```
git@github.com:account-name/repo-name.git
```

Comment: Is that your personal repo? Otherwise you usually need to fork the repo, then make a pull request into the original if you do not have permissions to directly push to the original.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43364233/5784831?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're acessing the remote through ssh. Make sure you have your ssh configuration working (You've generated a key-pair and copied the public key to your github account).

Easiest thing to try is to add the https:// equivalent as a remote instead.