# Clone a repo(not repository, the android repo) to you own account

Tags: git, github, repo, lineageos

I have cloned the lineageOS source using the repo command-line tool, I would like to make a clone of it in my own github account(they are NOT ONE SINGLE PROJECT! IT IS THOUSANDS OF REPOSITORIES PUT INTO ONE FOLDER!). after looking at the manifest, I felt there is some way to do it automatically. I googled, but it only shows results of how to clone a single repo, thats not what I want.

Final question: I would like to clone the entire LineageOS source, all the packages, apps etc, into my own account automatically.

Comment: Use github API? https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest

Comment: Just clone, then push? See e.g. here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43364619/5784831

Comment: @Christoph uhh its 100gb + it is not 1 repo ,it is a repo with repos inside

Comment: @jingx pretty sire it has a ratelimit!

Comment: Then I don understand, what you need exactly... Perhaps have also a look at submodules.

Comment: You only need to call the github api once (or occasionally periodically) to get all the repo urls. From there all you need is plain git clone/pull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no ratelimit on the api! so I just wrote a simple python script using PyGithub and voila, it cloned em all!