# What is the purpose of the "remote name" when adding a remote to VSCode

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code - I just chose to "add remote" so I can clone a repository and like every time, it asks me for a "Remote Name"
I feel there is redundancy here and I don't know where this "Remote Name" is actually used. I feel like I'm at the doctors office filling in the date 27 times on 3 pages of paperwork.

1. I've already had to create a filename for the folder in which I'm downloading the repository to,
2. I've already named the repository on Github,
3. and now I have to make a name for the remote.

What is the purpose of this "Remote Name"?
What should I name it?
Should I include information about the branch or something?

Thanks in advance for information about the best practice/workflow here, or anything my new programmer's mind doesn't yet grasp.

Comment: I can't speak to VSCode or any of the M$ stuff, but in raw Git, a *remote* is primarily a short, memorable name for a URL. Instead of remembering `ssh://git@github.com/jrandomuser/af31211/youllneverremeberTOusecapitalsinthemiddle/and/this/is/a/very/long/annoying/name/HAHA.git` every time, you just have to remember `thatguy`.

Comment: Most repositories are made by cloning exactly *one* original repository, so Git uses `origin` as the first default remote name, and on the command line, you type in: `git clone <url>` and press ENTER. Voila, you have one cloned repo, and to refer back to the saved URL (to get or send updates), you use the name `origin`. Nothing to remember, nothing extra to type in, ever.

Answer (score 0):

The `Git: Add Remote` command is from [VSCode 1.46 (Q2 2020)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62222605/6309), and is made to add remotes to existing local repository.

Asking for the `Remote Name` makes sense, since you are supposed to already have an existing local repository (possibly cloned from a remote one, referenced as "`origin`"): you might want another remote, named "`upstream`", to keep track of [an original repository that you have forked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6286877/6309).

Cloning a remote repository would be done with `Git: Clone`, which will automatically add the remote URL as "`origin`" for you, avoiding the redundant step of the "`Remote Name`" prompt.