# How to start using A remote Github Repository with Git bash

Tags: github

I am new learning Github.I made a repository on Github online,but there is not any local repository for that folder.Now when i am creating a new file in my local i want that to be pushed in my that remote repository.How can I connect that?

I started git bash on my local and tried to add that remote repo link,it didnt show any error..but when i tried to push a file there it showed me error.[image]

Comment: A different local repo was used to push changes, or perhaps edits directly on Github, and you don't have those changes locally. `git push` won't merge for you. You need to `git pull` to merge those changes with your local changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code - Connect to a remote Git repository and PUSH local files to a new remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364233/visual-studio-code-connect-to-a-remote-git-repository-and-push-local-files-to)